# Yahoo showing blank email body for php 5.4

Tags: php, email, yahoo

I have two boxes. One with PHP 5.4 and other with PHP 5.2

I am trying to send an email from box with php 5.4. Gmail is getting the email body correctly. Yahoo is getting a blank body.

Box with php 5.2 is sending the same email with valid body to yahoo.

It is just not working in 5.4 box.

DKIM headers passed in the email from 5.4 box.

Am I missing something?

```
function sendtestemail() {

    $newLineChar = "\n";
    $someEmailBoundaryy = "----=_".md5(uniqid(time()));
    $headerString = 'From: ' . "sender@example.com" . $newLineChar;
    $headerString .= 'Reply-To: ' . "sender@example.com" . $newLineChar;
    $headerString .= 'Return-Path: ' . null . $newLineChar;
    $headerString .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $newLineChar;
    $headerString .= 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' . $someEmailBoundaryy . '"' . $newLineChar;
    $messageText = "Some message without new line";


    $message = "--" . $someEmailBoundaryy . $newLineChar;
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8".$newLineChar;
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$newLineChar;
    $message .= strip_tags($messageText) . $newLineChar.$newLineChar;
    $message .= "--".$someEmailBoundaryy. $newLineChar;
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8".$newLineChar;
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$newLineChar;
    $message .= nl2br($messageText).$newLineChar.$newLineChar;
    $message .= "--".$someEmailBoundaryy."--" ;

    @mail ( "receiver@yahoo.com, receiver@gmail.com", "Test from sender", $message, $headerString , "-fsender@example.com");
}
```

Comment: Did you validate your handicrafted MIME body someway? (Such as not using CRLFs).

Comment: @mario : the message is just "Some message without new line" actually. It is not a place holder. this body is not sent

Comment: Again, fix your newlines then.

Comment: hi @mario. I was using a old version of mail component in cakephp and was trying to fix this new line issue. So i was very curious to learn how to build these headers. anyways, upgrading the mail component in cakephp helped the issue. But Im still looking into what exactly constitutes a correct header.

Comment: See RFC5321, 5322, RFC2045 etc.